# How to keep Font Size constant irrespective of device font size or screen density

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-fonts

I have kept my `EditText` font size as 16sp. However when I change the device font size, the `EditText` font size also changes. I tried using `dp` instead of `sp` which worked but I doubt if it will work well on different screens. How to I keep font size constant using `sp` as the unit irrespective on device font size and screen density?

Comment: Use `px`. Not recommended but give it a go.

Comment: Why do you doubt that `dp` will work? That will keep the text the same size regardless of device pixel density and will ignore the user's font size setting. @asadmshah -- using `px` will give different actual sizes on different screen densities, something OP doesn't want (at least that's how I read the question).

Comment: @TedHopp Doesn't `dp` resize based on the pixel density? `px` is constant and doesn't take anything into account which is why it's not recommended.

Comment: @asadmshah - dp resizes when measured in pixels but keeps the same size when measured in real-world dimensions (points, cm, inches, etc.). Using px results in visual resizing at different pixel densities; using dp results in constant visual size.

Comment: @asadmshah but wont using dp make the UI less attractive in ,say a tablet as it will look like a small font on big screen?

Comment: @AdityaSawant Not at all. Look at @TedHopp comment to see why using `dp` makes more sense than using `px`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dp`. The only difference between `dp` and `sp` is that `dp` will ignore the user's text size setting for the device. The result will be that the font size measured in real-world units (points, inches, etc.) will be the same on all devices, regardless of pixel density.

Note that screen size never affects any of this. If you want the text size to be defined in terms of a certain fraction of the screen dimension (e.g., width), there's nothing built into Android's unit system to support that. You'll have to either do the calculation in code (taking into account both screen size in pixels and pixel density) or define the size using alternative resources for different screen sizes.