# Font-size becomes too big when browser width is reduced

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, font-size

I am having a hard time with responsive text sizes:

```
<header class="toolbar">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
</header>
```

I have `font-size:2.4rem`. The font-size is perfect for laptop browser but it looks very small on my mobile phone browser. I realized that I need atleast `4rem` for mobile browsers. So to handle that, I implemented media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
            h1 {
                font-size:4.4rem;
            } 
        }
```

But when I reduce width of my laptop browse (<1000px), it works counter-intuitively because font-size increases to 4.4rem & look too big on laptop screen.

I tried `viewport` units (`font-size: calc(7px+0.5rem)`) but that didnt work either.

Comment: Are you trying to make the fonts [the same size regardless of pixel density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329019/how-to-keep-font-size-constant-irrespective-of-device-font-size-or-screen-density)?

Comment: If a larger than default (greater than 1em) font size looks small to you, I suggest checking your browser settings. Maybe you have changed *your* defaults. Also, realize that your media query with `max-width` matches when the screen is less than or equal to 1000px. Above 1000px, `h1` defaults to 2em.

Comment: What mobile and browser are you using? I ran your code and it did not give me the small font you describe if I removed the 4.4rem setting - iPhoneSE/Safari. Have you checked the rem setting in  your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

If you don't include this then the font will get bigger as the width increases:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If you do include it, then the font will (mostly) remain the same size regardless of width.

Because you haven't included a full page example, I don't know if you're already doing this, so I had to at least cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css :

```
html {text-size-adjust:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-moz-text-size-adjust:none;}
```

or

```
html {text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-moz-text-size-adjust:100%;}
```